# XAML - Binding error on a Slider.Value converter parameter inside a ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates, binding

I'm getting the following error when i try to bind some values to a control passed to a converter:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=Minimum; DataItem=null; target element is 'QuadraticSliderWrapper' (HashCode=9652842); target property is 'Minimum' (type 'Double')

Here is my code:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:PowersoftSDK.Controls">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:QuadraticSlider}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:QuadraticSlider}">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <Slider x:Name="QuadraticSlider"
                            Minimum="{TemplateBinding Minimum}"
                            Maximum="{TemplateBinding Maximum}"
                            SmallChange="{TemplateBinding SmallChange}"
                            LargeChange="{TemplateBinding LargeChange}"
                            MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}"
                            MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding MaxWidth}"
                            MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}"
                            MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxHeight}"
                            Orientation="{TemplateBinding Orientation}" TickPlacement="{TemplateBinding TickPlacement}" TickFrequency="{TemplateBinding TickFrequency}">
                            <Slider.Value>
                                <Binding Path="Value" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Converter="{x:Static controls:QuadraticToValueConverter.Default}">
                                    <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                                        <controls:QuadraticSliderWrapper Minimum="{Binding Path=Minimum, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                                     Maximum="{Binding Path=Maximum, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                                     Middle="{Binding Path=Middle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                    </Binding.ConverterParameter>
                                </Binding>
                            </Slider.Value>
                            </Slider>
                     </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
             </Setter.Value>
             </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I need to pass the templated values for max,min and middle to the QuadraticSliderWrapper.

Comment: Why are you passing a control as a command parameter?

Comment: Because i need to pass to the converter the values for max, min and middle as command parameter but if i bind to those values directily, in the converter  i get the dependency property instead of the value.